# Como obter o texto do <span>? mas quando se tem uma <img> nesse <span> da erro!

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

O seguinte código pega o `span`, mas se ele tiver uma `img` apresenta um erro.

```
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(names))
user.click()
```

Meu sistema pega o `title` do `span` e clica nele.
Mas quando o `title` vem seguido de texto e `img` não sei o que fazer.

Comment: Saudações, Carlos. Não sei se notou, mas estamos no [pt.so], então por que não posta sua pergunta em português? Convém fazer o [tour] e ler o guia de [ask] também. Se possível, cite exemplos do HTML em questão relacionados ao problema.

Comment: da pra entender ?